# nosetests producing ImportError

Tags: python, virtualenv, nose

`nosetests` throws an `ImportError` despite what I thought was a correctly-configured virtualenv.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named click)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/kmaxwell/src/flail/tests/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flail
  File "/home/kmaxwell/src/flail/flail.py", line 14, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named click

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using setuptools, so `setup.py` specifies

```
install_requires=[
    'click',
],
```

When I install with `pip install -e .` inside my virtualenv, I see the dependency install correctly. I've also installed nose inside the virtualenv.

What do I need to configure so that `nosetests` sees the imported package correctly?

Comment: Silly question, but are you running `nosetests` from within the virtual env? What do you get if you run `python -c 'import click'` in the venv?

Comment: Not silly! But yes, I'm definitely in the activated virtualenv. `python -c 'import click'` from the command line doesn't return an error.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I've got the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I got same error when I want to use nosetests with click today.
But I'm not using virtualenv.

Here is my solution, hope it is useful to you:

1. error when running nosetests

   ```
   > nosetests test2.py
   E
   ======================================================================
   ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named click)
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName
       addr.filename, addr.module)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
       return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
       mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
     File "/data/home/user00/tools/auto_open_server/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
       import click
   ImportError: No module named click

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 1 test in 0.001s

   FAILED (errors=1)
   ```
2. first find your `python` and `nosetests` path

   ```
   > which python
   /usr/local/bin/python

   > which nosetests
   /usr/local/bin/nosetests
   ```
3. make sure `click` is installed for `/usr/local/bin/python`

   ```
   > /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import click'
   ```
4. check the first line of `/usr/local/bin/nosetests`, it shows that the script is running with `/usr/bin/python` which is incorrect.

   ```
   > head -1 /usr/local/bin/nosetests
   #!/usr/bin/python

   > /usr/bin/python -c 'import click'
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: No module named click
   ```
5. modify the first line of `/usr/local/bin/nosetests` to `/usr/local/bin/python`

   ```
   > head -1 /usr/local/bin/nosetests
   #!/usr/local/bin/python
   ```
6. now I can run `nosetests` successfully

   ```
   > nosetests test2.py

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

   OK
   ```

Comment: Basically, you need to set the shebang line to the path where you install the module